# Collection of properties for undirected weighted graph that one can compute?

Tags: graph-theory

For a undirected weighted graph $G$ (no self-loop), there are many properties that one can try to compute (i.e. weighted matchings or perfect matchings, shortest path).

Are there some other interesting properties for $G$, especially with negative weights?

Comment: This is a very broad question. Interesting according to what/who? You can define all sorts of properties to compute any of which might be interesting.

Comment: hmmm, that's a good point @mrm